# com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.NoSuchMapperException

Tags: java, json

I write simple code, but it's not working.

Bean.class

```
package me.codeboy.lyd.test;

import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonField;
import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.annotation.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by yuedong on 6/26/15.
 */

@JsonObject
public class Bean {

    @JsonField
    @SerializedName()
    public String name ;
}
```

Test.class

```
package me.codeboy.lyd.test;

import com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by YD on 5/25/15.
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        test();
    }

    public static void test() throws IOException {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.name = "name";


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String source = gson.toJson(bean, Bean.class);

        System.out.println(source);

        LoganSquare.parse(source, Bean.class);

    }
}
```

I use Gson to generate json string , then I use LoganSquare to deserialize the json string, finally, the exception occurs. The exception is as follow:

```
    {"name":"name"}
    Exception in thread"main"com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.NoSuchMapperException:Class me.codeboy.lyd.test.Bean could not be mapped to a JSON object.Perhaps it hasn't been annotated with @JsonObject?
    at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.mapperFor(LoganSquare.java:165)
    at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.parse(LoganSquare.java:44)
    at me.codeboy.lyd.test.Test1.test(Test1.java:26)
    at me.codeboy.lyd.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:me.codeboy.lyd.test.Bean$$JsonObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.mapperFor(LoganSquare.java:161)
    ...8more

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs  `apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.1.0'`